# CakePHP Auth login

Tags: php, sqlite, cakephp

I'm sticking on a bug and I clearly doesn't know why it doesn't work.

My code is exactly [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) (I compared again and again for a mistake and I can assure you that my code is the very same as this)

**The problem :**

I keep getting "Wrong username/password" message, even is the informations are good. The account I'm trying to login have been created via the actual app (it worked) and the password is correctly hashed.

**EDIT :**

I changed my `$components` into my `AppController.php` for the following

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User',
            )
        ),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'admin-index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    ),
    'DebugKit.Toolbar'
);
```

and now, it login succesfully, even if the account doesn't exist... (that's very strange)

** EDIT 2 **

Here's the dump for `$this->Auth->User()` :

```
array(
'password' => '*****',
'username' => 'fdsf'
)
```

And here the login function :

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {

        if ($this->Auth->login())
        {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Mauvais nom d\'utilisateur ou mauvais mot de passe !');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the login function as well please, there are a few connecting parts here. It may be worth debugging the $this->Session / $this->Auth->User() to see what's being stored in the session. There shouldn't be a need for specifying the "Form" in this case as it defaults to "User". In other words leave 'authenticate' empty unless you have a different table or field names.

Comment: I updated the post with some infos. thanks for the reply

Comment: By the way, the account i try to loggin is admin/admin, I have no idea where this 'fdsf' come from...

Comment: Check you don't have any hardcoded values anywhere like in your view, run a global search for "fdsf" in Models/Controllers/Views. Did you attempt to remove the value within "authenticate"? So it's a just the key.

Comment: I only find 'fdsf' in a cache file, but nowhere the value has been hardcoded... well, all that time messing around with this... it's frustrating

Comment: what about your Appcontroller? Post code for registration as well?